# How to add email address in signup_form.html - Django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

My signup_form.html is as below, is there any way to add a email address in this form without changing views.py of back-end code?, I would like to let user fill in email adress when he is registering, [image]

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-12">
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what about to subclass from the given form class and add email field there, and render that your custom form instead of built-in standard form?

Comment: If render my custom form, I have to change views.py right? I would like to keep built-in standard form, because it is very simple, and it doesn't need views.py, it only has a signup_form.html

Comment: No u does not need to change a view, it will be rendered as standard form, but u add additional field to it.

Comment: If you want I can more widely explain in the answer, but I am from smartphone now and that will be a bit low quality, just simple logic.

Comment: @Chiefir Could you please widely explain in the answer? I can wait, thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If u use standard built in Django registration form- you can overwrite it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                         label='Email',
                         error_messages={'exists': 'Oops'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def clean_email(self):
        if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
            raise ValidationError(self.fields['email'].error_messages['exists'])
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

And next I guess if u said u does not have a view for registration (if I understand correctly) - u have similar string in your urls:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    urlpatterns = [
        path('register/', CreateView.as_view(
                template_name='register.html',
                form_class=UserCreationForm,
                success_url='/')
    ]
```

So you need just to replace `UserCreationForm` with your custom `UserCreateForm` here and that should work.

Comment: Hi Chiefir, my urls is as below: `patterns = [
    path('accounts/signup/', CreateView.as_view(), form_class=UserCreationForm, name='signup')`, and I got `TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form_class'`

Comment: What with that?

Comment: I use `patterns = [path()]` in my project, so I got that error, I think I need to change the grammar.

Comment: Check my post attentively. `CreateView.as_view()` - this is not what I have.

Comment: Thank you again for your patience, now I got error of `Reverse for 'signup' not found. 'signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` at base.py `<a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Sign up</a>`, signup_form.html and signup.html is under folder templates/registration, and now path is `    path('accounts/signup/', CreateView.as_view(template_name='registration/signup.html', form_class=UserCreationForm, success_url='/'),`

Comment: i think you need to have an `app_name` before your url in your template. like `{% url "your_app_which_is_defined_in_urlspy_file:signup" %)

Comment: Hi, I didn't change path, I only add `UserCreateForm` in form.py, now front-end page already has email filed, I can fill in email, but email wasn't saved into database............It's weird....